# Js function top calculate factorial not working

Tags: javascript

I was doing this challenge from coderbyte where you have to make a function that calculate the factorial of a given number, this is my not so working solution.

```
function firstFactorial(num) { 

  for (var i = num; i == 1; i--) {
      num = num * i;
  }
  return num;     
}
```

It just returns whatever number i pass in as an argument, and i'm trying to understand what's wrong. Is it something to do with the loop or is it something with the variable scope ?

Comment: Is that your whole code?

Comment: `i == 1` is a weird loop condition

Comment: `for(var i = num; i == 1; i--){` that will only execute if `i == 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `i == 1` is wired in loop condition it will always be false for all number except 1.So it will always return the same number as result.
2. `i = num` should be `i = num-1` to get correct factorial.

```js
function FirstFactorial(num) {
  
  for(var i = num-1; i >= 1; i--){
      num = num * i;
  }
  return num;     
}

console.log( FirstFactorial(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop was a bit messed up. Now it should work.

```js
 function factorial(num){
 for(var i = num - 1; i > 0; i--){
      num *= i;
  }
  return num;     
}

console.log(factorial(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have a loop condition `i == 1`. For factorials, it should be `i >= 1`, or `i > 1` depending on what algorithm you use. My take on a factorial function would be:

```
function calculate(factorial) {
    var newFactorial = factorial;
    while (factorial > 1) {
        factorial--;
        newFactorial *= factorial;
    }
    return newFactorial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function firstFactorial(num) {
    const output = eval(Array.from({length: num}, (_, index) => (index + 1)).reverse().join("*"));
    return output;  
}

console.log(firstFactorial(8));
```

Rather than iterating through all the numbers using `for` loop or `recursion`. I used built-in Javascript functions.
I first created an array of length `1-N` using `Array.from`
Then, I reversed that array and joined it with `*`. Then, I used the `eval` function to get evaluate the expression.
You can also shrink it down to just one line. So the code will be:
`const findFactorial = num => eval(Array.from({length: num}, (_, index) => (index + 1)).reverse().join("*")`